# Math notation understanding

Tags: evaluation, interpretation

I was reading a paper where I got the following notation which I am finding it difficult to understand especially inside the summation part.

[image: purity]

Here I see max notation with this condition 1<=j<=k. How this notation with max is interpreted? The value of i changes with summation itself ranging between 1 to the value of Ncm. How is the value of j changing here? Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want help with mathematical notation, you want the [math site](http://math.stackexchange.com). We answer questions about writing computer programs here.

Comment: Wait, [you already asked this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784670/need-to-understand-this-summation-with-max-notation) on the math site, and you got an answer. Why are you posting this here?

Comment: Sorry. I actually forgot that I posted my question there as it was few months back. Indeed, I usually come to this site to get answer for programming related problems. It was completely out of my mind that there is math site for the above math related questions. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

For some detail example,

`i` & `j` makes up a math matrix.

Every `i` has many `j`, you should choose the value `n_ij(max)` to cauculate the formula.